# How to implement facebook signin in cqrs?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am learning cqrs and event source and trying to use it in my project. And I was stuck in the 1st step: facebook sign in.

What I want to implement is the controller for the facebook callback. The basic logic is very simple, just search the existing users if it has been registered, if it is return the userid, otherwise create a new user, and return the new userid.

My questions are: in this command handler, is it ok to search the user read model? By doing that, search and create user are not in one transaction and it will have a concurrency issue. If not ok, what is the best way to do that?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is not something CQRS should be used for .. pick something with real business logic ..

The external system  ( the login ) could provide a success event and fail event  , which you can use to populate the read model.

Comment: Totally agree.. CQRS is about solving a business problem, and its not a solution wide architecture. It is OK to mix and match CQRS with CRUD and any other patterns.